# Appends are not cached in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-cache

I'm trying to cache an object in Laravel.

```
$categories = Cache::remember('categories', 10, function () {
    return Category::with('forums')
    ->select('id', 'name')
    ->orderBy('order')
    ->get();
});
```

The problem is that I have some appended values in the Forum model.

```
protected $appends = ['number_of_topics', 'number_of_replies', 'last_post'];

public function getNumberOfTopicsAttribute() {

    return Topic::where('forum_id', '=', $this->id)
        ->count();

}

public function getNumberOfRepliesAttribute() {

    return Reply::whereExists(function ($query) {
        $query->select(DB::raw(1))
            ->from('topics')
            ->whereColumn('topics.id', '=', 'replies.topic_id')
            ->where('topics.forum_id', '=', $this->id);
    })->count();

}

public function getLastPostAttribute() {

    $lastPost = new LastPost($this->id);

    if ($lastPost->topic_id == null) {

        return null;

    }

    return $lastPost;

}
```

All appended values are not cached. How to make them cached along with $categories?

Comment: check this package https://github.com/bennett-treptow/laravel-cached-mutators

Comment: An accessor transforms an Eloquent attribute value when it is accessed. What about if you do `Cache::get('categories')->first()->forums->first()->number_of_topics;`?

Comment: I cached every append attribute individually and it worked